# get value of current scroll position by js

Tags: javascript, html

I need if user scrolled to `<a id="stass">`
this script runs

```html
<script>
if(current id is stass){
      var stassik = 1231;

}
</script>
```

The part with `if(current id is stass)` it s where I need to get info about current anchor. I mean, if user scrolled to this anchor, the var `stassik`  will become `1231`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using IntersectionObserver API to achieve this.
For more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API